# Why does rookie cop Jessica Loren shoot these characters?

Tags: plot-explanation, last-shift

In the climax of the 2014 movie *[Last Shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Last_Shift)*, rookie cop Jessica Loren kills the HAZMAT guys, thinking them to be ghosts (or whatever), and later, when she is shot by the Sergeant, she comes to her senses and realizes that they were Hazmat guys.

So in the movie's story, did she have some sort of mental disorder that made her think of ghosts, and other effects in movie? Or were there ghosts that made her to feel like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The very short answer is that the film's director, Anthony DiBlasi ***has [openly stated](http://www.dreadcentral.com/news/131525/anthony-diblasi-walks-us-last-shift/) that he wants the audience to be conflicted over whether what Officer Loren is seeing is real or imagined*** (and would presumably be very pleased to see that it worked!).

---

At that end of the film our hero has been subjected to numerous instances of *seemingly* supernatural events; being attacked by undead creatures, repeatedly scared by people who subsequently disappear. On top of that, she also seems to be suffering from borderline psychosis brought on by stress and lack of sleep.

The fact that she experiences a "moment of clarity" at the end (when she realises that what she thought was a Satanist cult was in fact the HAZMAT team) which would imply that the ghosts were in her own mind, but that's just *my opinion*.

> **DC:** *In the film there are instances of Satanic activity, claustrophobia, and a ton of jump scares – what is it about this movie
>   that’s going to scare the crap out of people?*
>
> **AD:** *I think the main component of it is that you’ve essentially got one character that takes you on a journey, and you’re in her point
>   of view through the entire movie, and I think that helps a lot for
>   viewers to just settle in and experience everything as she does.
>   **Every corner that she lurks around, there’s something waiting for her, and it’s always in her point of view – is it just playing with
>   her mind, or is this a full-on haunting?** It’s a really important
>   element of the film, just keeping that momentum going for a fresh
>   experience.*